# How can I extract the values that don't match when joining two RDD's in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, join, apache-spark, rdd

I have two sets of RDD's that look like this:

```
rdd1 = [(12, abcd, lmno), (45, wxyz, rstw), (67, asdf, wert)]
rdd2 = [(12, abcd, lmno), (87, whsh, jnmk), (45, wxyz, rstw)]
```

I need to create a new RDD that has all the values found in `rdd2` that don't have corresponding matches in `rdd1`. So the created RDD should contain the following data:

```
rdd3 = [(87, whsh, jnmk)]
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: `def subtract(other: RDD[T]): RDD[T]` "Return an RDD with the elements from this that are not in other."

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Perfect, it looks like this is the best way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a full join and then create 2 new RDDs.

1. Select where both tables had records
2. Select where RDD2 PK is present and RDD1 is null

You'll need to first convert them to KV rdds. Sample code below:
    rdd3 = rdd1.fullJoin(rdd2).filter(x => x._3.exists).map(x => (x._1, x._3.get))

(Yes, there is a more idiomatic way to get the option but this should work)

Comment: There's nothing in the question about these being keys and values. And even if it was by-key, `subtractByKey` would be better